# How do I set a constant in setup() that I can use in loop()?

Tags: arduino-uno, code-optimization

I am new with coding, and I was wondering how I could run something once and define it as a constant. Here is my code:

```
int sensorValue1 = analogRead(A0);  
int sensorValue2 = analogRead(A1);  
int g0 = 9.81*9.8;  
int h1 = 48;  
int R = 287.06;  
int a = -0.0065;  

void setup() {   
    Serial.begin(9600);  
    int p1 = (1.09512*sensorValue2-22.105)*133.3225;  
    int t1 = (-0.08126*sensorValue1+65.6597)*274.15;  
}

void loop() {
    String t = "Temperature:    ";  
    String tt = " Celsius";  
    String p = "Preassure:    ";  
    String pp = " Pascal";
    float celsius = -0.08126*sensorValue1+65.6597;     
    float kelvin = celsius*274.15;
    float pascal = (1.09512*sensorValue2-22.105)*133.3225;  
    float height = (t1/a)*((pascal/p1)^((a*R)/g0))-1)+h1;  
    Serial.println(t+celsius+tt);  
    Serial.println(p+pascal+pp);  
    Serial.println(kelvin);  
    Serial.println( );  
    Serial.println(height);  
    delay(1000);  
}
```

Comment: What do you need to run something once? Put in inside "setup" method (it gets executed once the Arduino powers up or gets reset)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, and there's other things wrong with your code.

```
int sensorValue1 = analogRead(A0);  
int sensorValue2 = analogRead(A1);
```

Calling functions from the global scope is an incredibly bad idea.  Those are run *before* the board has been properly initialized, and the results you may get from it are not guaranteed in any way, shape, or form.  Instead you must call functions like `analogRead()` from within another function, like `setup()`, or `loop()`.

As for `const` - a `const` is just that - a constant value that can **never** change.  You can only assign a value to it at the moment of creation.

And that means that you can only use it within the *scope* it was defined within.  As you can't do that in the global scope (see above) then you *cannot* use a constant.

So just use a normal global variable.  It will only change when you tell it to change.  Using a `const` only makes sense when you have a *numeric literal* that you want to refer to by name. Using `const` doesn't protect the variable from being changed at run-time by memory leaks, etc, it just protects it from attempts to modify it at compile time - and if possible replace it with the numeric literal that it refers to.

So in summary just use:

```
int sensorValue1;
int sensorValue2;
int p1;
int t1;

void setup() {
    sensorValue1 = analogRead(A0);
    sensorValue2 = analogRead(A1);
    p1 = (1.09512*sensorValue2-22.105)*133.3225;
    t1 = (-0.08126*sensorValue1+65.6597)*274.15;
}
... etc ...
```

**HOWEVER**: Your program methodology is also completely flawed.  You read the analog values once, and do calculations with them once, then repeatedly display the same values over and over again.

You **must** perform a *new* `analogRead()` of your sensors every iteration of `loop()` in order to update the values in your variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can define Constants using the "const" keyword. Ex:

```
    const float pi = 3.14;
    const int foo = 12;
```

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Const

Comment: However scope rules mean that variables declared in `setup()` won't be visible in `loop()` – to make them visible declare them outside of any function.